# Check if one of multiple variables exists in array

Tags: php

```
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
$vars = ['a', 'f', 'g'];

foreach ($vars as $var) {
    if (in_array($var, $array)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can i check if one of the `$vars` exists in `$array`? Only one of them needs to be `true` if all the others are `false` it is not a problem, But if there is more than 1 `true` value,

For example `['a', 'b', 'c', 'g']` i want the function to stop at the first `true` value and ends the process.

Comment: Don't `return false` until you've checked everything. Move the `return false` under the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, the code you've got in the question is pretty much the best way to go about this. You just need to move the `return false` to after the loop, so that all values get processed:

```
foreach ($vars as $var) {
  if (in_array($var, $array)) {
    return true;
  }
}

return false;
```

This will work identically to a solution with `array_intersect`, but has the advantage of only needing to process the minimum amount of the loop. Consider the following data:

```
$vars = [1, 2, 3, 4, ... 1,000,000,000];
$array = [1, 10, ...];
```

A solution using `array_intersect` will need check **every** element in `$vars` against **every** element in `$array`, whereas a solution that breaks out of a loop will only need to check until the first match. You could optimise this further by using two nested `foreach` loops if both your arrays are very large.

Like I mentioned in the comment - if your arrays are small then just use `array_intersect`, you won't notice any difference, and the code is a bit more readable.

Comment: wouldn't `return false;` override `return true` if there is a match in this form?

Comment: No - the function will only run until the first `return` statement it reaches. Nothing after that point gets processed.

Answer (score 5):

Simply with `array_intersect` function:

```
$arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
$vars = ['a', 'f', 'g'];

$result = count(array_intersect($vars, $arr)) == 1;    
var_dump($result);   // true
```

Comment: It needs to be `>= 1`, no? Also, the downside of using array_intersect instead of a basic loop is that you can't break at the first successful result, so it's not as performant. Although for small arrays that's not an issue.

Comment: @iainn i guess `== 1` would be better, Since i don't want the user to type more than two valid values.

Comment: @AXAI Maybe I misunderstood then. I thought multiple matching values was ok? You just wanted to check for *at least* 1. Anyway, if it works for you then that's the important thing.

Comment: @iainn No problem, But as i understood from you that `array_intersect` isn't faster than a `normal loop`? or is it a small difference in performance if the arrays aren't big?